# Running spring-boot webapp in windows

Tags: spring-boot

How can I run springBoot web app in windows with embedded tomcat? When I run the target war as ./target-snapshot.war, I am getting an error saying ' C:\Program: command not found'.

When I use the same command in unix, it works like a charm.

Comment: Go to the folder where `target-snapshot.war` exists in Command Prompt and then run your command.

Answer (score 0):

Program Files has a space.  When using a command like `./doit.bat c:\program files\something\something` it will treat that as to arguments due to the space.  Surround the whole `"c:\program files\..."` section in quotes so it is treated as one argument.